# Why does count(DOMNode->childNodes) return an incorrect number of children? (PHP and XML)

Tags: php, xml, dom, count

I have a PHP function called processDeleteForm() designed to remove a specified node from an xml document named structure.xml. The only problem I'm having with it so far is that in processDeleteForm(), it searches for the node to be removed by looping through each child node of the parent node, and matches it by the "name" attribute, but I haven't been able to get the correct number of child nodes for the loop, so it stops before it reaches the correct node. Relevant code:

```
function processDeleteForm($dir, $filename)
{
  echo "Processing delete request.<br/>";
  echo "Request to delete ".$filename." from ".$dir.".<br/>";
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

  $xmlDoc->load("structure.xml");
  $node = dirDOMNodeWritable($dir, $xmlDoc);

  $target;
  echo "Working directory has ".count($node->childNodes)." child(ren).<br/>";
  for($x = 0; $x < count($node->childNodes); $x++)
  {
    if($node->childNodes->item($x)->getAttribute("name") == $filename)
    {
      $target = $node->childNodes->item($x);
      echo "Target found.<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Searching for target...<br/>";
    }
  }

  if($target->getAttribute("type") != "directory")
  {
    $fstored = "uploads/".$target->childNodes->item(0)->wholeText;
    unlink($fstored);
  }

  $node->removeChild($target);

  $file = fopen("structure.xml", "w");
  fwrite($file, $xmlDoc->saveXML());

}
```

structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<directory name="root" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
  <directory name="music" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
    <directory name="She" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
      <directory name="Chiptek" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
        <directory name="mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
          <file name="intro.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">intro.mp3</file>
          <file name="music.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">music.mp3</file>
          <file name="supersonic.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">supersonic.mp3</file>
          <file name="memories.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">memories.mp3</file>
          <file name="chiptek.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">chiptek.mp3</file>
          <file name="intermission.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">intermission.mp3</file>
          <file name="kicks.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">kicks.mp3</file>
          <file name="1997.mp3" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/mpeg">1997.mp3</file>
        </directory>
        <directory name="ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="directory">
          <file name="intro.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">intro.ogg</file>
          <file name="music.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">music.ogg</file>
          <file name="supersonic.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">supersonic.ogg</file>
          <file name="memories.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">memories.ogg</file>
          <file name="chiptek.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">chiptek.ogg</file>
          <file name="intermission.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">intermission.ogg</file>
          <file name="kicks.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">kicks.ogg</file>
          <file name="1997.ogg" owner="elarsen" read="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" write="aclum,ahoffman,apavlowski,bvollmer,dpotts,drichardson,epiatt,jcantrell,jreeve,kdouglas,kjab,lbrewer,lholliday,mfriedman,norty,pmoore,rlongwell,scatlett,sketcherside,tperkins" type="audio/ogg">1997.ogg</file>
        </directory>
      </directory>
    </directory>
  </directory>
  <directory name="test01" owner="elarsen" read="0" write="0" type="directory"/>
  <directory name="test02" owner="elarsen" read="0" write="0" type="directory"/>
  <directory name="test03" owner="elarsen" read="0" write="0" type="directory"/>
</directory>
```

*The above is supposed to be the contents of an xml file, but I can't figure out how to display it as such. If somebody with more knowledge about formatting xml on stackoverflow could fix it, I would be much obliged.

It might also be useful to see the code responsible for the creation of the directories named "test01", "test02", and "test03":

```
function processNewForm($dir, $dirName, $readPrivs, $writePrivs)
{
  $readString = "";
  $writeString = "";
  $dirOwner = $_SESSION["user"];

  for($x = 0; $x < count($readPrivs); $x++)
  {
    $readString += $readPrivs[$x].",";
  }
  for($x = 0; $x < count($writePrivs); $x++)
  {
    $writeString += $writePrivs[$x].",";
  }

  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

  $xmlDoc->load("structure.xml");
  $node = dirDOMNodeWritable($dir, $xmlDoc);

  $newDir = $xmlDoc->createElement("directory");
  $newDir->setAttribute("name", $dirName);
  $newDir->setAttribute("owner", $dirOwner);
  $newDir->setAttribute("read", $readString);
  $newDir->setAttribute("write", $writeString);
  $newDir->setAttribute("type", "directory");

  $node->appendChild($newDir);

  $file = fopen("structure.xml", "w");
  fwrite($file, $xmlDoc->saveXML());

}
```

The current output looks like this:

```
Received delete request.
Validating delete request... Request is valid.
Processing delete request.
Request to delete test03/ from /.
Working directory has 1 child(ren).
Searching for target...

Notice: Undefined variable: target in E:\aepi\dev\fileshare.php on line 540

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in E:\aepi\dev\fileshare.php on line 540
```

Comment: What does this `dirDOMNodeWritable()` function do?

Comment: It creates a DOMNode representing the directory path passed in the $dir variable from the XMLDocument passed in $xmlDoc, so that when I try to modify the structure of $xmlDoc using $node, it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [PHP manual for count()](http://php.net/count):

> Returns the number of elements in var. If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned.

[`DOMNode::$childNodes`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) is a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/DOMNodeList) object. It is not [`Countable`](http://php.net/Countable). It will always return one (even if empty). Use its [`length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) property instead:

```
$count = $element->childNodes->length;
```

**Update:** `DOMNodeList` has been made `Countable` from PHP 7.2 onwards.

Comment: I feel really, really dumb now. I was somehow convinced that I had used count() elsewhere in my code for this purpose when I had actually been using length. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, I installed PHP 7.3 on apache on a Windows 10 device and count() actually worked on DOM as expected. Coming back to my Mac with PHP 7.1 on High Sierra and it only returns the single first node.

Comment: @VasilyHall From the change log on the referenced doc page, `DOMNodeList` has been made `Countable` in 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your `childNodes` is including text nodes along with the XML tag nodes due to the white space in between tags.  This can result in a count of `childNodes` twice what you expect it to be.  You should check the `nodeType` to make sure it isn't a text node before attempting to get its attributes.

Possibly in here:

```
  for($x = 0; $x < count($node->childNodes); $x++)
  {
    // Verify that you're not working on a text node (type 3 TEXT_NODE)
    if($node->nodeType != 3 && $node->childNodes->item($x)->getAttribute("name") == $filename)
    {
      $target = $node->childNodes->item($x);
      echo "Target found.<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Searching for target...<br/>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I put the whitespace in the xml code above solely for readability purposes. structure.xml exists on the server without intervening whitespace. Besides, if that were the case, it would be reporting **more** children than I want, not less, no?

Comment: I must have missed that it was reporting fewer than expected. Sorry.

Comment: I was wondering why I was getting a childNodes count that is twice the actualy number of children. This post helped me!